# DataGridView XElement filtering via Textbox text

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq, datagridview

here is my "project":

[image: project]

What I'm trying to do is to load data from an external .xml file into the DataGrid:

```
XElement Persons = XElement.Load(@"d:\persons.xml");
dataGrid1.DataContext = Persons;
```

It works just fine, but here is an issue which I can't figure out: at the top of DataGrid you can see TextBox so what I need is to use the textBox1.text as a data filter for DataGrid. Let's say if user input letter "a", in DataGriw we should see only 2 rows, with name pAul and row with country russiA, cause both rows contain letter "a" in it's data. If you will also help me to include and exclude some columns abilitiness for search it would be just brilliant. And finally, if user click on the row he found using a search button - data from the sells should be placed to the labels at the right. I also would be happy to know how to load data of the selected row which is not actually shows in DataGrid. Let's say if in xml file we have data about salary, but we do not shown it in DataGrid and we need it to be loaded to the 4th label when user do a row selection. Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="679" Width="1137">
<Grid Height="645" Name="grid1" Width="1119">
    <DataGrid Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[person]}" Margin="26,42,839,297" Name="dataGrid1" Width="250">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Element[name].Value}" Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Element[country].Value}" Header="Country" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Element[age].Value}" Header="Age" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" />
    <Label Content="Name goes here on row select" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,28,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" />
    <Label Content="Country goes here on row select" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,72,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" />
    <Label Content="Age goes here on row select" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,120,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" />
</Grid>
```

Please talk to me like to the absolute beginner, cause it's hard for me to understand when you use something extra smart. Step by step is highly appreciated. Thank you...

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you asking about searching the XML with LINQ to XML? Or are you asking about some code to update the UI?

Comment: I'm asking about how to filter results in datagrid using the textbox. In Windows Forms I was using data set filter but here I've no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the Datagrid you need to create a CollectionViewSource and assign it to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid:

```
private void Load()
{        
        XElement Persons = XElement.Load(@"d:\persons.xml");

        System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView c = System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Persons.Elements());
        c.Filter = new Predicate<object>(CollectionViewSource_Filter);

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = c;
}

private Boolean CollectionViewSource_Filter(object i)
{
        return (i as XElement).Element("name").Value.ToString.Contains(textBox1.Text);
}
```

To refresh the DataGrid when the filter has changed, this method is needed: `c.Refresh();`

If the filter should be case insensitive, have a look at [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Displaying the name of the selected person:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Element[name].Value, ElementName=dataGrid1}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this code return me couple errors, here they are:
Error 1 The best overloaded method for "System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView (object)" has some invalid arguments
Error 2 Argument "1": type conversion of "group methods" in "object" disallowed
Error 3 "object WpfApplication1.MainWindow.CollectionViewSource_Filter (System.Xml.Linq.XElement)" has the wrong return type

Comment: Error 4 Can not implicitly convert type "System.Predicate <System.Xml.Linq.XElement>" in "System.Predicate <object>". There is an explicit conversion (due to missing cast)
Error 5 "string.ToString (System.IFormatProvider)" is a "method", which is not allowed in this context

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I wrote the code in VB.NET and then just converted it to c# without testing the result. See my updated post please.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to work now!! I'll be really happy if you help me to load value of the selected row into the labels (at the right side: label1, label2 and so on). The most unclear thing for me is how to get value of a 4th element "salary" (which is not shown in the dataGrid but exist in .xml file) for a selected row and place it into label4.

Comment: Because of databinding it is quite simple. You can replace "name" with all other attributes from the xml file, even "salary".

Comment: It works fine while using via XAML, I'm try to use it in backend code. Something like label1.Content = dataGrid1.SelectedItem.Element("name").value; but it doesn't work, where am I've mistake?... Tell me please, is it OK that for textBox1 text changed void I write Load(); - if I get it right, everytime I use textBox for a searching - programm will bind data again and again but with applying filter specified. Is it fine for performance?

Comment: To update the labels in code, `label1.Content = dataGrid1.SelectedItem.Element("name").Value` must be called every time the event `SelectionChanged` of the DataGrid occurs. For better performance you can place the `System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView` object outside the method `Load` and then call only `c.Refresh()` when the text has changed.

Comment: label1.Content = dataGrid1.SelectedItem.Element("name").Value returns with an error: Error 1 "object" does not contain a definition for "Element" was not found an extension method "Element", given to the type "object" as the first argument (due to missing a using directive or an assembly reference) - help me to figure it out please

Comment: As the property SelectedItem is of the type object you need to convert it to the type XElement first and you have to check if it is not null, otherwise there will be a NullReferenceException: `if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem != null) label1.Content = (dataGrid1.SelectedItem as XElement).Element("name").Value;`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!!! You helped me a lot, Alu!!! Your help is so appreciated!